# Problem to data access from sql db by using r studio

Tags: sql, r, database

I can able to connect DB by using following code

```
library(RODBC)
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
conn3 <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc :: odbc(),
                        Driver = 'SQL Server',
                        Server = 'xxx',
                        Database = 'xxx',
                        UID = 'xxx',
                        Pwd = 'xxx',
                        TrustServerCertificate='no',
                        #trusted_connection = 'yes',
                        Port = 1433
)
```

And i can able to see the DB data table.

But when i try to access the data by using following code

```
myquery <- dbSendQuery(conn3, "SELECT  * FROM mhealthpbi1.report.blood_test")
df<-dbFetch(myquery)
```

It showws the following error

```
Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:3069: 07009: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index
```

and show the error message (image attached)

can anyone help me to access or extract data?

can anyone help me to access or extract data by providing code or explain process?

Comment: Any updates to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try `myquery <- dbSendQuery(conn3, "SELECT * FROM mhealthpbi1.report.blood_test;")` or make sure the table name is correct, remember that you have already selected the database in dbConnect.

Example for mySQL:

```
mysqlconnection = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                            dbname='cars',
                            host='localhost',
                            port=3306,
                            user='xxx',
                            password='xxx')

brand = fetch(dbSendQuery(mysqlconnection, "select brand from sale_2018"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this error can be caused by a MS ODBC-driver (ahem) "feature": all long columns (ill-bounded constraint) must be at the end of the list of columns<sup>1</sup>. I'm inferring that you have an `odbc` version older than 1.3.1, since it was sufficiently mitigated in that release.

Two options:

1. See if/which columns are "large", often created as `nvarchar(max)` or `blob`:

   ```r
   fields <-
     DBI::dbGetQuery(conn3,
       "select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
        from information_schema.columns
        where TABLE_NAME='blood_test'")
   ```

   Look at `fields`, and if `character_maximum_length` is over -1 (max) or *possibly* a high number over 255 or so, then that column should be at the end. In this case, you'll need to change from `select *` to specific columns. (Many SQL gurus discourage `select *` anyway, for reasons relating to defensive programming and unsupervised/automated queries.)

   If you really "need" `select *`, then I suggest you write a sql `VIEW` that orders the columns correctly, and then allows one to `select *`. Crafting this is rather simple assuming that the user permissions in the database allows it. If so, then it may be as simple as

   ```sql
   CREATE VIEW myview AS
   select column1, column3, column5,
     bigcolumn2, bigcolumn4
   from mhealthpbi1.report.blood_test
   ```

   and then subsequently use `select * from myview`.
2. Update your version of `odbc-1.3.1` or newer (1.3.3 is current as of this writing), as it should resolve the issue.

Notes:

1. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/getting-long-data